# Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not support error when import json data into elastic

Tags: elasticsearch

MY Code below

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/p
ost/_bulk/"  -d @City_collection.json
```

error:
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not support
ed","status":406}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the content-type header like this

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/post/_bulk/" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @City_collection.json
                                                                ^
                                                                |
                                                            add this
```

Comment: I've updated my answer, use double quotes instead of single quotes since you're on Windows

Comment: thks for your answer Val ..but in my system i am still getting error when import large json fileinto elastic..i dont know how to do it...

Comment: Glad we solved the content type header issue. Feel free to create a new question with the specific error you get. And also show a portion of the JSON file you're trying to upload.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52178390/incorrect-http-method-for-uri-test-and-method-post-allowed-put-head-d