# Elasticsearch showing error 406 when inserting

Tags: macos, elasticsearch

Just installed ElasticSearch on my mac (`brew install elasticsearch`).

Then started it with: `brew services start elasticsearch`.

I can see it is running:

```
curl localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "84ucGje",
  "cluster_name" : "elasticsearch_dnk306",
  "cluster_uuid" : "yU6wdZpJT_-1OvaFf7l7Ug",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "6.5.0",
    "build_flavor" : "default",
    "build_type" : "tar",
    "build_hash" : "816e6f6",
    "build_date" : "2018-11-09T18:58:36.352602Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "7.5.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "5.6.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "5.0.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

When I try to add some index to it - it fails with 406 error:

```
curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/1 -d '{"title":"Hello world"}'
{"error":"Content-Type header [application/x-www-form-urlencoded] is not supported","status":406}
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try this `curl -XPOST localhost:9200/test/1 -H 'Content-Type: application/json -d '{"title":"Hello world"}''` ?

Comment: also which version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: this answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52177340/4604579